# how to spell data from RpostgreSQL to table structure

Tags: r

I'm running to following scrip

```
library("knitr", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
library("markdown", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
library("ggplot2", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
library("RPostgreSQL", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
conn <-dbConnect(drv,host=xxx,port='5439',dbname='stats',user=zzz,password=yyy)
dbListConnections(drv)
Data1 <-dbSendQuery(conn,"select family,date(ts),count(*),count(distinct uid)as Users from mr_session_log group by family,date(ts) order by date(ts)")
fetch(Data1,n=-1)
```

and receiving the results i want but when i want to spell the data to table structure with the following code

```
Data1_df <- data.frame("Data1")
```

and I'm trying to run view(Data1_df), i received only one row with one column with the value Data1.

how can i spell the data i received after fetch(Data1,n=-1) into table structure (i want to run some graphs on that table)

attached the data1

```html
                     family       date count users
1                     Other 2015-08-31  1000    12
2                     Other 2015-09-01  3156    74
3                     Other 2015-09-02  1258    12
4                     Other 2015-09-03  1116    31
5                     Other 2015-09-04   794    28
6                     Other 2015-09-05   390    14
7                     Other 2015-09-06   250    15
8         Samsung SM-G900FD 2015-09-07    72     1
9                     Other 2015-09-07   227     7
10                  LG D956 2015-09-07    47     1
11         Samsung GT-N7105 2015-09-07   245     1
12         Samsung SM-N910C 2015-09-07    24     1
13               Motorola   2015-09-07  3315    37
14         Samsung GT-I9505 2015-09-07   108     1
15         Samsung SM-N910F 2015-09-07   394     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try

```
data <- fetch(Data1,n=-1)
```

But you rather should use

```
Data1_df <- dbFetch(Data1,n=-1)
```

instead of `fetch`, since `fetch` will be deprecated soon.

Additionally, if you run the `data.frame` function, you don't have to quote the object, so you would rather use

```
Data1_df <- data.frame(Data1)
```

Comment: i received the error below                                                                          Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("PostgreSQLResult", package = "RPostgreSQL")" to a data.frame

Comment: Can you tell me what you see for str(Data1)?

Comment: i put the data1 in the question

Comment: Try Data1_df <- dbFetch(Data1,n=-1) instead of fetch sinde fetch will be deprecated in 2015.